# Is the sentence "We see this problem be unsolvable." grammatically correct?

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-constructions

This is supposed to be the correct answer to one of the exercises from a B2 textbook written by a non-native author.

It struck me as odd, but my teacher (also a non-native speaker) told me that such constructions are acceptable in formal written English. Is she right?

Comment: Perhaps on [International Talk Like a Pirate Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Talk_Like_a_Pirate_Day)...

Comment: Thank you for asking. When a question asks for proofreading or rewriting (“how should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, “which is correct?”), that is out of scope for this site and may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” try asking that question instead. Also check out: “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”.

Answer (score 2):

Like [user321630's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/471106/102510) I would also regard this as wrong, probably suggesting:

> We see this problem **to be** unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to see this in a student's work I would most likely mark it wrong or suggest a change like:

> We see this as an unsolvable problem.

It's current construction feels unfinished or as if there were typos.

Comment: Or, possibly, "_We see this problem **to be** unsolvable._"

Comment: Please add that as an answer. It keeps with the infinitive tag that was put on the post and it is a good answer.